# Limit of a function of two variables as they go to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

The *Mathematica* software returns the limit of
$$\left(1 - \frac{k}{k + m + 1}\right)^{1/2}$$
as $k$ and $m$ go to $+\infty$ to be $1$.

How does it calculate this? If we first let $m$ goes to $\infty$, the result becomes $1$. However, if we first let $k$ goes to $\infty$, the limit becomes $0$. And, if we treat both $k$ and $m$ to be the same at infinity, the limit becomes $1/\sqrt{2}$.

How is $1$ the correct result?

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Raffaele Thanks for your comment. I'm looking for a mistake in my argument on the mathematics' side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to expect $\underset{k\to \infty}\lim\underset{m\to \infty}\lim f(k,m),\ \underset{m\to \infty}\lim\underset{k\to \infty}\lim f(k,m)$ and $\underset{(m,k)\to \infty}\lim f(k,m)$ to return the same value. If you write out the formal definitions of these, and draw a picture using matrices, you will see how they differ. To see how Mathematica is getting its result, you need to check which of these definitions the software uses.

Comment: To add to this - I feel sometimes that mathematical analysis can be sometimes be succinctly summarized as the study of "when limits commute"!